# Using user inputted email for JavaScript firebase

Tags: javascript, email, firebase, user-input

I am following this guide: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/password.html

They have hardcoded strings as the email and password.

How can I get the user to input there own values and submit it to the database?

```
 <form action="" onsubmit="createUser()">
      Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
      Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br>
      Repeat Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Sign up" >
    </form>
```

I have this code above and would like to use this so that the user can enter whatever email they like and be registered. However, the docs only seem to cover hardcoded strings?

Comment: Perhaps you should review this: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/saving-data.html

Comment: What does your `createUser()` function do? If you're trying to call `ref.createUser()` it won't work that way.

Comment: @BryndenBielefeld sorry if I am being stupid but it all seems hardcoded still?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a following way:

```
let email = document.getElementById("email")
let password = document.getElementById("password")
```

Call firebase function

```
app.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then((res:any)=> {

    // some code

}
```